# How do I get a overall result?

Tags: sql

In our card-club (Skat) we play one time every week in the year, so everyone can have a maximum of 52 results.
We determine our Season-Champion in such a way as we add the 21 best results and the 5 worst.
I've two SQL-Statments to get the 2 results:

::: For the 21 best results :::

```
SELECT rs.Season, rs.Name, SUM(rs.Pkt) AS Pkt_Max21 
    FROM (SELECT 
            Season, 
            Name, 
            Pkt, 
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (Partition BY Name ORDER BY Pkt DESC ) AS Row,
            RANK() OVER (Partition BY Name ORDER BY Pkt DESC ) AS Rank
          FROM Gameresults
          WHERE Season = (SELECT Year FROM Evaluation) 
          AND Member = 1) rs 
WHERE rs.Rank <= 21 
AND rs.Row <= 21 
GROUP BY rs.Name 
ORDER BY Pkt_Max21 DESC
```

::: And for the 5 worst :::

```
SELECT rs.Season, rs.Name, SUM(rs.Pkt) Pkt_Min5
    FROM (SELECT 
            Season, 
            Name, 
            Pkt,
                        Rank () OVER (Partition BY Name ORDER BY Pkt ASC ) AS Rank
                FROM Gameresults
        WHERE Season = (SELECT Year FROM Evaluation) 
        AND Member = 1) rs 
WHERE rs.Rank <= 5 
AND rs.Name IN (SELECT Name FROM Gameresults WHERE Season = (SELECT Year FROM Evaluation) AND Member = 1 GROUP BY Name HAVING COUNT(Name) >= 26)
GROUP BY rs.Season, rs.Name 
ORDER BY Pkt_Min5 DESC
```

Now my question:

How do I get these two results combined to one result.
I tried many times, but didn't get the right answer.
What I know is, that I have to rename rs to maybe **top** for Pkt_Max21 and maybe **bottom** for Pkt_Min5.

Comment: Please add some simple data and the expected output, Also share the RDBMS you are using

Comment: Sorry, but I didn't ask the whole question. The answers from SelVazi and ORA-01017 work very well. But I need a result as follow:

Comment: The answers from SelVazi and ORA-01017 work very well. 
But I need a result as follows: 
If a player have less then 22 results, he only gets the sum of these results 
e.g. player have 6 results (100, 200, 300, 400, 500) 
he'll have 1500 points as Pkt_Max21 but 0 (zero) for Pkt_Min5.
If a player has more than 21 results but less then 26 he gets the sum of the highest 21 results as Pkt_Max21 and 
the sum of the remains as Pkt_Min5.
All others the highest 21 as Pkt_Max21 and the least 5 as Pkt_Min5, no matter whether he has 26 or 52 results

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Rank` and `group by` with `HAVING` as follows:

```
SELECT rs.Season, rs.Name, SUM(rs.Pkt) AS Pkt_Max21 
    FROM (SELECT 
            Season, 
            Name, 
            Pkt, 
            RANK() OVER (Partition BY Name ORDER BY Pkt DESC ) AS Rank_desc,
            RANK() OVER (Partition BY Name ORDER BY Pkt asc ) AS Rank_asc,
          FROM Gameresults
          WHERE Season = (SELECT Year FROM Evaluation) 
          AND Member = 1) rs 
WHERE rs.Rank_desc <= 21 
AND rs.Rank_asc <= 5
GROUP BY rs.Name, rs.Season
Having max(rs.Rank_desc) >= 26
ORDER BY Pkt_Max21 DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you can use either `rank()` or `row_number()`, you don't have to use both.

The following method combines both results into a single row for each Season and Name:

```
WITH rs as (
  SELECT Season, Name, Pkt,
         RANK() OVER (Partition BY Name ORDER BY Pkt DESC ) AS Rank_max,
         RANK() OVER (Partition BY Name ORDER BY Pkt ASC ) AS Rank_min
  FROM Gameresults g
  INNER JOIN Evaluation e on g.Season = e.Year 
  WHERE Member = 1
)
SELECT Season, Name, SUM(CASE WHEN Rank_max <= 21 THEN Pkt ELSE 0 END) Pkt_Max21,
                     SUM(CASE WHEN Rank_min <= 5 THEN Pkt ELSE 0 END) Pkt_Min5
FROM rs
GROUP BY Season, Name
```

---

You have also the option to combine them in a way that each type of counting in a row we can use `UNION ALL` :

```
WITH rs as (
  SELECT Season, Name, Pkt,
         RANK() OVER (Partition BY Name ORDER BY Pkt DESC ) AS Rank_max,
         RANK() OVER (Partition BY Name ORDER BY Pkt ASC ) AS Rank_min
  FROM Gameresults g
  INNER JOIN Evaluation e on g.Season = e.Year 
  WHERE Member = 1
)
SELECT Season, Name, SUM(CASE WHEN Rank_max <= 21 THEN Pkt ELSE 0 END) AS total, 'Pkt_Max21' AS flag
FROM rs
GROUP BY Season, Name
UNION ALL
SELECT Season, Name, SUM(CASE WHEN Rank_min <= 5 THEN Pkt ELSE 0 END), 'Pkt_Min5'
FROM rs
GROUP BY Season, Name
HAVING COUNT(Name) >= 26
```